# SQL Datetime Convert Error

Tags: sql, datetime

I have have an SQL Statement which returns following error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

```
SELECT * FROM eBV_Platz 
WHERE (ADRID = 4436) AND (ID <> 5) AND (Status = 1)  
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.03.2014', 102) >= PlaceFrom) 
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.03.2014')  <= PlaceTo)
OR (CONVERT(DATETIME, '31.03.2014') >= PlaceFrom) 
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, '31.03.2014') <= PlaceTo)
```

But this one works fine and the only difference are the date values:

```
SELECT * FROM eBV_Platz 
WHERE (ADRID = 4436) AND (ID <> 5) AND (Status = 1)  
and (CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2000', 102) >= PlaceFrom) 
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2000')  <= PlaceTo)
OR (CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.06.2001') >= PlaceFrom) 
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.06.2001') <= PlaceTo)
```

I really don't understand this. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try changing 31.03.2014 date to 03.31.2014.

Comment: The DB is interpreting '31.03.2014' as the 3rd of the 31st month.  Use the YYYY-MM-DD format to avoid these issues.

Comment: Anything else you need help with? Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting that the second one does not work fine, rather it converts your dates to january 06 and january 01.

You need to give it a hint that you are using a day month year format.

Try instead:

```
(CONVERT(DATETIME, '31.03.2014', 103)
```

The 103 ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)) interprets the date as `dd/mm/yy`

As @AlexK noted in the comments, these dont really need to be converted.  You could simply use the strings as long as they were in a better format.

My assumption here is that you are using MSSQL.  For a different platform, the syntax would be different.

Comment: January 1 and January 06, is what it incorrectly converts them to. June 01 would be correct. :)

Comment: @SamDeHaan, you are correct! transposed them as i was writing.

Comment: The dates a literal, just change them to a better format, don't run them through a function

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, use [ISO 8601 date format](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) to specify dates (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss[.mmm]`).

This would change `'31.03.2014'` to `'2014-03-31T00:00:00.000'` and remove any ambiguity.